# Multi level inheritence in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have come across a question recently on multilevel inheritance in java, the question is as follows :

```
 public class Test{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A c = new C();
            c.print();
        }

    }
    class A{
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("Inside A");
        }
    }

    class B extends A{
        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("Inside B");
        }
    }
    class C extends B{

    }
```

So my question is why this is printing as **"Inside B"**. Because class C is not overriding the method print() and hence it should resolve the method based on compile time and hence should print **"Inside A"**. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thank you for your help.

Comment: _it should resolve the method based on compile time_   - That is false

Comment: Class B is overriding class A so now class B's method will be called. Class C extends B not A, it will call the last overriden method, not the original. Hence class B's print method is called. Unless class C overrides the print method it will default the the last overriden method which is class B's print method.

Comment: Why do you think that `C` should skip the overriden method of its direct parent and use the one of his "grandparent" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C extends B, which means that it will have the same methods as B and it this case B has overridden the method, thus C will also have it.

Answer (score 1):

It's printing "Inside B" because that is the class that C is extending, and B is thus C's superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two things.

If a method is overridden one or more times, the version in the most specific subclass will run. That is why the version in `B` is the one used.

On the other hand, when choosing between overloaded methods, the decision is based on the compile time type of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is of type `A`, but the `A` itself was initialised as instance of `C` , and since `C` extends `B` and `B` overrides `A`, the both `B` and `C` override method inside `A`. But since `C` does not override `B`, the method used is from B.

Got to say, that is pretty neat brain exercise.

Answer (score 1):

By the laws of inheritance in Java, all functions in the base class are used by derived classes including ones that are overridden. Any class that inherits from an intermediately inherited class will take the overridden definition. This is self-evident as these overridden functions override any function definition before it in the inheritance hierarchy. Therefore, the overridden function acts as a base class definition of any derived class underneath it.